# How to call the react function/method from the javascript callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**javascript code:**

```
 var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.innerHTML = "var onloadCallback = function() { 
       grecaptcha.render('html_element', { 
         'sitekey': '' , 
         **'callback':validateCaptcha** 
      });};"
    document.head.appendChild(script);
```

**react code :**

```
    validateCaptcha (response)
    {
        alert(response); 
    }
```

@note: we have scenario like creating the captcha dynamic using the create element and we need to call the  react method/

Comment: Your code looks like okay. What is the problem? isn't it working?

Comment: its says undefined validateCaptcha   ,, note:this is the react validateCaptcha   method